# CSS - h1 take rest of width

Tags: html, css, width

In my titlebox I have an icon (`<img>`) and a title (`<h1>`). Both are floated to the left.

I would like my title (`<h1>`) to take up the rest of the width of the box. So if I put text-decoration: underline; on the `<h1>`, the underline must go on to 'till the end of the box.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44XDa/1/

Basically I want the line under Welcome to go 'till the end of the yellow box.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make the `h1` float if the only other element in the area is already floating. As the other posters have already pointed out, you probably want to use a border rather than an underline to get this effect. Here are my edits:

http://jsfiddle.net/44XDa/36/

The main difference between my solution and those above is that this one doesn't set a width for the `h1` element. This will make it easier if you decide to alter the width of the content-title `div` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this changes](http://jsfiddle.net/44XDa/22/)

I used border bottom to simulate the underline to the end. I reduced your line height and added padding top to place it where you had it. Remove the text decoration and you'll have a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/44XDa/34/

Might this be what you want?

Comment: Thanks, but that solution kind of breaks it when you change span2 to e.g. span1. I guess I can specify h1 width for each span, is that the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

**[*Live demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/44XDa/39/)**

Hey now used to `box-shadow` and remove **h1** `float left` as like this and manage to **bottom line** as `line-height`

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44XDa/39/)***